# Como utilizo el DATE_FORMAT de MYSQL en Oracle?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Necesito convertir una linea de mysql a oracle y encontre como pero aun me sale error en la fecha en cual dice ORA-01821: formato de fecha no reconocido

codigo mysql

```
DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-01-01') AND current_timestamp()
```

codigo oracle

```
TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-01-01') AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

muchas gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Lo que es incorrecto para Oracle es el format que estás usando, ya que no se pueden usar números:

```
'YYYY-01-01'
```

Lo correcto sería:

```
TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

¿Por qué usas el 01-01, quieres lograr una fecha que sea el 01/01 del año actual?
En ese caso podrías usar:

```
TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(year from sysdate) || '-01-01')
```

Comment: Sii lo que quiero lograr es que me saque el registro desde el primer dia y mes de un respectivo año

Comment: TRUNC(sysdate, 'Year'), si quieres hacerlo con alguna otra fecha que no sea sysdate deberías reemplazar sysdate por la fecha que quieras.